# how to pass a checkbox value using <a href

Tags: php, jquery

example.php ~ when i check the checkbox in example.php webpage.. then i click the print button, the value will be pass on example1.php

```
if($items) {    
    foreach($items as $i)
    {
        print"<input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value='$i->logi_id'>";
    }
}

echo "<a href='example1.php?checkbox=" . $checkbox . "'><input type='button' name='print' id='delete' value='Print'></a>"
?>
```

---

example2.php

```
<?php
$keyword = $_REQUEST['keyword'];
$keycateg = $_REQUEST['keycateg'];
$print = $_REQUEST['print'];    
$checkbox = $_REQUEST['checkbox']; 
$count = count($_REQUEST['checkbox']);

if($print){
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){    
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
        $sql = "select * FROM sampleDB WHERE logi_id='$del_id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i want to pass the value of the textbox in example2.php .. .. my problem is solve using <form action=..> but i need is using href.. ty

Comment: Probably not your problem, but `id='checkbox[]'` is not valid. IDs may only contain letters, numbers, hyphens, underscores, periods, and colons, and the first character must be a letter.

Comment: thx sir barmar for advice T_T sorry im a newbie here..

Comment: And you need to wrap `$i->logi_id` in `{...}` to get proper substitution in the string.

Comment: One other thing: putting a button inside <a></a> is not valid, and doesn't work in some browsers. If you want a button to act like a link, use `<button onclick='location.href="..."'/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple words ---

```
checkbox=<?php echo $checkbox; ?>
```

but dont rely on user inputs,...sanitize the data

Comment: @Barmar lol ...haven't give much eye on that... ;) thx 4 the info :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you want to submit the form using a link, prefered way would be to style a submit button as a link, but you could ofc use javascript to submit the form using a link. you can find a more indepth explanation here

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Answer (score 0):

I guess his question is how he can evaluate the current value of the checkbox and use it in a a href "GET" encoded style.

I would recommend not using a href, but using another form with post method "get" (that encodes the url for you).
Else your are stuck with javascript I believe.

Comment: actually sir Najzero. the main problem in my program is i want to pass the value of the checkbox in another webpage. the value of checkbox is a result of query in database..

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkbox_string = htmlentities(http_build_query(array('checkbox'=>$checkbox)));

echo "<a href='example1.php?$checkbox_string'>...</a>"
```